# Relative CSS layering problems

Tags: css, z-index

I am running into a couple of problems with layering of relative `<div>`s. Now one of the problems is that when you zoom in, it messes everything up and also something that I want to do is have two releative layers under the wrapper layer. But every time I try to do this, even when using `z-index` it messes everything up. So is there any soloutions to both of these problems, index code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Arakion - Homepage</title>
<html>
<link href="font/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<head>
<style type = "text/css">
body,td,th {
    font-family: KingthingsExeterRegular;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
}
a:link {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
}
a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="images/Backgrounds/Left.png" name="left" width="192" height="533" style="float:left; z-index:-9999; position:relative;" />
<img src="images/Backgrounds/Right.png" width="191" height="530" style="float:right; z-index:-9999; position:relative;" />
<div id="Wrapper">
  <div id="navbar" style="display: inline-block;">
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="top">
        <a href="#">HOME</a>
    </li>

    <li id="top">
        <a href="#">GUIDE</a>
        <ul>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="#">CLASSES</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="#">DUNGEONS</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="#">MONSTERS</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="#">PETS</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="#">RACES</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="#">TOWN BUILDINGS</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="#">UNIVERSE</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="#">WIKI</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="top">
        <a href="#">BLOG</a>

        <ul>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="#">ARAKION</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="#">CHRIS TAYLOR</a></li>
        </ul>

    </li>
    <li id="top">
        <a href="#">MEDIA</a>
        <ul>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="#">CONCEPT ART</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="#">SCREENSHOTS</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="#">VIDEOS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="top">
        <a href="#">FORUM</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;" id="sidebar_header"><img src="images/Progress/KickstarterGoalBar_0.png" width="310" height="80"/></div>
<div style="display: inline-block;" id="sidebar_banner">
  <div id="Sidebar_content">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Social Media</p>
    <p><img src="images/Side Banner_Line.png" width="100%" height="10" /></p>
    <p><a herf="#" target="_new"><img src="images/KickstarterIcon.png"/></a> <a href="http://www.indiedb.com/games/arakion" target="_new"><img src="images/IndieDBIcon.png" width="35" height="35" /></a> 
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/Arakion" target="_new"><img src="images/FacebookIcon.png" width="35" height="35" /></a> <a href="http://twitter.com/arakiongame" target="_new"> 
            <img src="images/TwitterICon.png" width="35" height="35" /> </a> <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/MrLavidimus" target="_new"> <img src="images/YoutubeICon.png" width="35" height="35" /> </a> </p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Random Media</p>
    <p><img src="images/Side Banner_Line.png" width="100%" height="10" /></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Something</p>
    <p><img src="images/Side Banner_Line.png" width="100%" height="10" /></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div></div>
<div style="display: inline-block;" id="main_background">
  <div id="main_content"><div id="main_img"><img src="images/MainImages/Main_Placeholder_img.jpg"/></div>
    <table width="600" height="106" border="0" id="main_section_img" style="margin-left: 15px;">
      <tr>
        <td width="140"><img src="images/MainImages/Placeholder1.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%"/></td>
        <td width="140"><img src="images/MainImages/Placeholder2.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%"/></td>
        <td width="140"><img src="images/MainImages/Placeholder3.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%"/></td>
        <td width="140"><img src="images/MainImages/Placeholder4.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%"/></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <center>
    <table width="561" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="140">How Housing Works and why we have it</td>
        <td width="140">An In depth look at the Satyr race</td>
        <td width="140">We take a look at the role the alchemist plays in a group</td>
        <td width="140">Our doors are offically open to new employees apply today</td>
      </tr>
    </table></center>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div></div>
<div style="display: inline-block;" id="sub_background_1"><div id="sub_content">
  <div id="Sub_title">Kickstarter has just opened!</div><div id="Sub_subtitle">by Chris Taylor 7-24-2012</div><div id="Sub_image" style="display: inline-block;">
    <img src="images/MainImages/Sub_Placeholder.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%"/></div>
  <div id="Sub_text"> sUt enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt  ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, <a href="index.html">Read More.</a></div></div></div>
<div style="display: inline-block;" id="sub_background_2"><div id="sub_content">
  <div id="Sub_title">Kickstarter has just opened!</div><div id="Sub_subtitle">by Chris Taylor 7-24-2012</div><div id="Sub_image" style="display: inline-block;">
    <img src="images/MainImages/Sub_Placeholder.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%"/></div>
  <div id="Sub_text">  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt  ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, <a href="index.html">Read More.</a></div></div></div>
<div style="display: inline-block;" id="sub_background_3"><div id="sub_content">
  <div id="Sub_title">Kickstarter has just opened!</div><div id="Sub_subtitle">by Chris Taylor 7-24-2012</div><div id="Sub_image" style="display: inline-block;">
    <img src="images/MainImages/Sub_Placeholder.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%"/></div>
  <div id="Sub_text"> sUt enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt  ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, <a href="index.html">Read More.</a></div></div></div>
<div style="display: inline-block;" id="sub_background_4"><div id="sub_content">
  <div id="Sub_title">Kickstarter has just opened!</div><div id="Sub_subtitle">by Chris Taylor 7-24-2012</div><div id="Sub_image" style="display: inline-block;">
    <img src="images/MainImages/Sub_Placeholder.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%"/></div>
  <div id="Sub_text">  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt  ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, <a href="index.html">Read More.</a></div></div></div>
<div id="footer_background" style=" text-align: center; ">
    <img src="images/Footer_Divider.png" height="10px" width="600px"/>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
COPYRIGHT 2012 CHRIS TAYLOR ALL RIGHTS RESERVED | CODED BY <a href="http://seanwhall.daportfolio.com/" target="_blank">SE</div>
```

Css Code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'KingthingsExeterRegular';
    src: url('kingthings_exeter-webfont.eot');
    src: url('kingthings_exeter-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('kingthings_exeter-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('kingthings_exeter-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('kingthings_exeter-webfont.svg#KingthingsExeterRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
body {
    font-family: 'KingthingsExeterRegular';
}
#full-screen-background-image {
  z-index: -999;
  width:900px ;
  height:800px ;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
/*Body Css */
#Wrapper {
    width:1040px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:200px;
    z-index:5;
    position:relative;
}
#left{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    z-index:!important -9;  
}
#right{
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    z-index:!important -9;  
}
/*------------------------------------*\
    NAV
\*------------------------------------*/
#navbar{
    position: static;
    top:5px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-left:5px;
    width:650px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index:4;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
#nav{
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:600;
    height:50;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
#top{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-image:url("../images/Button_NavBar_Unselected.png");
    height:55px;
    width:120px;
    margin-bottem:5px;
    font-size:15px;
}
#top li:hover{

}
#submenu{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    height:20px;
    width:100px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#nav a{
    display:block;
    padding-top:20px;
    z-index:-1;
    font-family:"Arial";
}
/*--- DROPDOWN ---*/
#nav ul{
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px; /* Hide off-screen when not needed (this is more accessible than display:none;) */
}
#nav ul li{
    padding-top:1px; 
    float:none;
}
#nav ul a{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#nav li:hover ul{ 
    left:-30px;
    top:40px;
}
#nav li:hover a{ /* These create persistent hover states, meaning the top-most link stays 'hovered' even when your cursor has moved down the list. */

}
#nav li:hover ul a{ /* The persistent hover state does however create a global style for links even before they're hovered. Here we undo these effects. */

}
#nav li:hover ul li a:hover{ /* Here we define the most explicit hover states--what happens when you hover each individual link. */

}
/* Main Block */
#main_background{
    width:680px;
    height:519px;
    float:left;
    background-image:url(../images/MainSection.png);
}
#main_content{
    width:590px;
    height:430px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:45px;
}
#main_img{
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:5px;
    background-image:url(../images/MainSection_BigImageHighlight.png);
    width:520px;
    height:300px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:4px;
}
#main_section_img{
    margin-top:10px;
    background-image:url(../images/MainSection_SmallImageInsett.png);
    width:560px;
    height:95px;
}
/* Sub Block */
/*  Sub Background Hierarchy */
#sub_background_1{
    position:relative;
    width:610px;
    height:270px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(../images/SubSection_Base.png);
    z-index:-1;
    margin-left:30px;
    top:-38px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#sub_background_2{
    position:relative;
    width:610px;
    height:270px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(../images/SubSection_Base.png);
    z-index:-2;
    margin-left:30px;
    top:-52px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#sub_background_3{
    position:relative;
    width:610px;
    height:270px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(../images/SubSection_Base.png);
    z-index:-3;
    margin-left:30px;
    top:-65px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#sub_background_4{
    position:relative;
    width:610px;
    height:270px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(../images/SubSection_Base.png);
    z-index:-4;
    margin-left:30px;
    top:-77px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#sub_background_5{
    position:relative;
    width:610px;
    height:270px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(../images/SubSection_Base.png);
    z-index:-5;
    margin-left:30px;
    top:-83px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#sub_background_6{
    position:relative;
    width:610px;
    height:270px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(../images/SubSection_Base.png);
    z-index:-6;
    margin-left:30px;
    top:-81px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#sub_background_7{
    position:relative;
    width:610px;
    height:270px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(../images/SubSection_Base.png);
    z-index:-7;
    margin-left:30px;
    top:-81px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#sub_background_8{
    position:relative;
    width:610px;
    height:270px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(../images/SubSection_Base.png);
    z-index:-8;
    margin-left:30px;
    top:-85px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
/* Hierarchy End */
#sub_content{
    width:580px;
    height:220px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:10px;
}
#Sub_title{
    height:35px;
    width:400px;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-left:10px;
    font-size:30px;
    text-align: left;
}
#Sub_subtitle{
    height:20px;
    width:200px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:65;
    font-size:15px;
    text-align: left;
}
#Sub_image{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:15px;
    float:left;
}
#Sub_text{
    height:180px;
    width:400px;
    float:right;
    margin-top:10px;
    text-align: left;
}
/* SideBar Block */
#sidebar_header{
    position:relative;
    height:80px;
    width:350px;
    float:right;
    background-image:url(../images/Kickstarter.png);
    margin-right:5px;
    left:-20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    z-index:1;
}
#sidebar_header img {
    margin-top:61px;
    height:18px;
    width:310;

}
#sidebar_banner{
    position:relative;
    height:729px;
    width:360px;
    float:right;
    background-image: url(../images/Side%20Banner.png);
    left:-20px;
    z-index:-1;
}
#Sidebar_content{
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:20px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 20px;
    width:300px;
    height:700px;
    line-height: 3px;
}

/* Footer */
#footer_background{
    position:relative;
    background-image:url(../images/Footer.png);
    width:605px;
    height:75px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:35px;
    top:-89px;
    z-index:-9;
    line-height:1px;
    font-family:"Arial";
    font-size:10px;
}
#footer_background img {
    margin-top:100px;
}
```

The way the site is now, is basically what happens when you zoom in. It is also what happens when I try to add the two images inside two relative div layers.
Site: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/49665279/Arakion/index.html Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've just experienced the closing and reopening of a question. The best lesson I learnt which I can pass on is that I recommend that you make this question more concise. Consider an edit, removing excess code, focussing only on your question. I will however, attempt to provide an answer.

As i understand it, the two images you're referring to are the images in the background. seen as you have fixed the width of all your page's elements you can do the following:

Create a single image which contains both left and right with the required whitespace in between.(drawback being that the image includes whitespace, which is wasteful).

Then add the following to your body element's css:

```
background: url('url/to/your/new/twoimage.jpg'); 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

A quick google of "fixed versus fluid layouts" should shed some light on defining widths.

Using safari, the page never ceases loading. I recommend firebug http://getfirebug.com/
It is a fantastic tool for inspecting web page issues. 
Feel free to ask more specific questions